# React print axios POST response on page on submit

Tags: reactjs

[image]I have a working axios post request to my flask server that returns json in its response which looks like this.

```
{contract: 135.35699844360352}
```

I can see this response in the console where I logged it but I am having trouble understanding how to render it onto my page.

My main goal is to take the working response data and display on the page via the render() html.

Here is the Form.js file from React:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ticker: "",
    };
  }

  handleTickerChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ticker: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000", this.state)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({ contract: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Ticker </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="ticker"
            value={this.state.ticker}
            onChange={this.handleTickerChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        {this.state.contract}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: could you log your response?

Comment: yes the response was logged and working

Comment: can you update the response in your post?

Comment: not sure what you mean. i can change the response so i get different data in the console. yes

Comment: I want you to see it

Comment: i have added a screenshot of the console to the post

Comment: So console.log(response.data) is {contract: 135.35699844360352}?

Comment: yes i just want to display the data under my form on my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handleSubmit function check response.data
if it is {contract: 135.35699844360352} you need change setState function to

```
 this.setState({ contract: response.data.contract });
```

or

```
const {contract} = response.data
this.setState({ contract: contract });
```